# Why is it "L'état d'esprit de la chanteuse est la peur." and not "L'état d'esprit de la chanteuse est peur."

Tags: grammaire, traduction, adjectifs, articles

I thought "peur" meant "fear". So in the phrase "L'état d'esprit de la chanteuse est la peur.", I used at first "peur". So the phrase would say "The mood of the singer is fear". However, on google translate it changes "peur" to "la peur". In the sentence wouldn't that make it: "The mood of the singer is the fear"?

Answer (score 2):

Uncountable/generic nouns are a case where English doesn't use an article while French does.

*L'eau coule* - Water flows.

*Le temps, c'est de l'argent* - Time is money.